# Using 3D photos in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, image-processing, silverlight-4.0, 3d

I want use photos captured by 3D cameras in Silverlight 3 or 4.
I want use that photos like in maps.google.com. Is it possible to do with silverlight and if yes is there any book, tutorial, video or anything alse, from which I can learn how to use tham.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with panoramic images.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883038/hlsl-for-getting-cylinder-effect) is example for cylindric images.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to convert a stereoscopic images to an Anaglyph in Silverlight.

Have a watch of this video from Mix10 [Moving at 60fps](http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/CL25).  You want to be 55 minutes into the video (its mainly about video but the principles are the same).

Unfortunately Eric doesn't provide any access to the pixel shader in question.

Comment: I wathced the video, but have no idea how to use it for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check this demo out. It comes with full source code:
http://www.evanjohnston.com/post/Silverlight-4-Webcams-to-the-3rd-Dimension.aspx

They use two webcams and red- and green-filter pixel shaders to separate the streams. Of course the same can be used for static images.