# HLSL for getting cylinder effect

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, directx, hlsl, pixel-shader

I need to write an application with Silverlight 4 and need to show images like wrapped on cylinder. I need some HLSL code, as I wont to do that with Effects of Silverlight.
I don't wont to do that with 3D libarries for silverlight. I only need HLSL code for changing pixels.
I need for my image to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tn6gg.jpg) [image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the effect you want, you may wish to change the 0.2 value to increase or decrease the effect or make this adjustable in your shader but that's a simple change to do. I'd recommend [Shazzam](http://shazzam-tool.com/) if your not using it for writing shaders for WPF or Silverlight.

```
sampler2D input : register(s0);

float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR 
{ 
    float y = uv.y+(sin(uv.x*3.14) * lerp(-1,1,uv.y) * 0.2);
    if(y < 0 || y > 1)
        return float4(0,0,0,0);
    else
        return tex2D(input,float2(uv.x,y));
}
```

Comment: Hi @Kris. Unfortunatly I can't try this right now, because I haven't compiler on this computer, but I will try this tomorrow. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Exelent solution. Exactly what I need. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

While you *could* do this with HLSL if you really wanted to, you'd *normally* do it by creating a mesh in the shape you want, then applying the picture to the mesh as a texture.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Of course it will work, but I don't wont to use mesh, I know, that it is possible by using effects in Silverlight.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607748/how-wrap-image-around-cylinder-in-silverlight This link is nearly like what I need.