# image show pixel by code

Tags: silverlight

I have an image control that contain an image.
I want to show the image by code, displaying random pixel of the original image.

Is it possible?

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are asking. Could you provide more details on what effect you are trying to achieve?

Comment: sounds like you want to implement "disolve type" pixel shader

Answer (score 0):

You need pixel shader effect for your image.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883038/hlsl-for-getting-cylinder-effect) is example of usage effects.