# WP7 Silverlight 3D Cylinder

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, 3d, wpf-controls

I'm looking for some xaml implementation of 3d Cylinder which i can use in WP7, i heard about Balder but, as i tried it looks like project is not ready to be used on WP7.

Answer (score 0):

For anything 3D you should look into using xna.

Comment: I know that i can use xna, but it is not what i was asking for. I asked for xaml implementation, because i used XNA, and rendering with UIElementRenderer is a bit slow, so my SL animations not looks good.

Comment: with the 7.1 sdk, you might be able to do something using pixel shaders like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883038/hlsl-for-getting-cylinder-effect but I cannot guarantee it. silverlight is optimised for 2d and xna for 3d.